# How to execute powershell script in sitecore from remote with parameter

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am having a curious case about Sitecore Powershell Extensions. I have created a .net based Cmdlet which I can execute after using import command with required parameters.
Now I want to automate this cmdlet by scheduling it in external system as I don't trust the Sitecore Scheduler. So for that I write a new function using ISE in Sitecore and saved as 'Powershell Script' item.
Following is the code:

```
    function Execute-Auto-Site-Backup {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Backups the given site path while looking for delta based on last execution time.

        .PARAMETER Item
            Item to sync, Usually a Root Item, Need to specify Sitecore Guid of Root Item.

        .PARAMETER ItemList
            Specifies the list of item which need to be excluded, It is in pipe separated GUIDs.

        .PARAMETER UserName
            Sitecore Username for taret webservice "sitecore\admin"

        .PARAMETER Password
            Sitecore Password

        .PARAMETER HostURL
            Sitecore instance Host URL

        .PARAMETER DBName
            Sitecore target Database name, if not passed default is "master"

        .PARAMETER LangName
            Sitecore Source Language name, if not passed default is "en"

        .PARAMETER IncludeChildren
            Indicate if need to copy the all children till nth level of indicated root item, if not passed default is false which means it will execute for single item

        .PARAMETER BackupMode
            Indicate if need to create versions always or just update the existing latest version, if not passed default is true which means it will create version in the target item

        .PARAMETER VersionNumber
            Sitecore Version number of Item to get, Default will be the Latest if not provided. In case of multiple item it will always take latest version.

        .PARAMETER LookupMode
            To use History Engine, if not passed default is false which means always look in iterative mode from passed root node.

        .PARAMETER DateTime
            If LookupMode is History Engine than this parameter will define since when to look, ideally this is last time the backup job has run. Date Time should be in following format and as per server time zone '1/20/2015 3:30:00 PM'

        .EXAMPLE    
            BackupMode as version(non-update) always and LookupMode is single item(non-history)

            [string[]]$paracs=@("{7589EBFF-FB47-41A0-8712-E34623F5518E}","","sitecore\admin","target","http://10.0.0.5/","master","en","false","true","0","false","")

        .EXAMPLE        
            BackupMode as version(non-update) always and LookupMode is iterative(non-history) in childrens

            [string[]]$paracs=@("{7589EBFF-FB47-41A0-8712-E34623F5518E}","","sitecore\admin","target","http://10.0.0.5/","master","en","true","true","0","false","")

        .EXAMPLE
            BackupMode as update(non-version) always and LookupMode is iterative(non-history) in childrens

            [string[]]$paracs=@("{7589EBFF-FB47-41A0-8712-E34623F5518E}","","sitecore\admin","target","http://10.0.0.5/","master","en","true","false","0","false","")

        .EXAMPLE
            BackupMode as update(non-version) always and LookupMode is single item(non-history)

            [string[]]$paracs=@("{7589EBFF-FB47-41A0-8712-E34623F5518E}","","sitecore\admin","target","http://10.0.0.5/","master","en","false","false","0","false","")



        .EXAMPLE        
            BackupMode as version(non-update) always and LookupMode is history(non-iterative)- most used way and preferred for automate backups

            [string[]]$paracs=@("{7589EBFF-FB47-41A0-8712-E34623F5518E}","","sitecore\admin","target","http://10.0.0.5/","master","en","","true","0","true","1/20/2015 3:30:00 PM")

        .EXAMPLE
            BackupMode as update(non-version) always and LookupMode is history(non-iterative)

            [string[]]$paracs=@("{7589EBFF-FB47-41A0-8712-E34623F5518E}","","sitecore\admin","target","http://10.0.0.5/","master","en","","false","0","true","1/20/2015 3:30:00 PM")
            #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Item,

        [string]$ItemList,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$UserName,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Password,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$HostURL,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$DBName,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$LangName,

        [string]$IncludeChildren="false",

        [string]$BackupMode="true",

        [string]$VersionNumber,

        [string]$LookupMode="false",

        [string]$DateTime
    )    
    $path=$AppPath+"bin\PG.SharedSitecore.AssemblyTools.CoreSync.dll"
    Import-Module $path -Verbose
    [string[]]$paracs=@($Item,$ItemList,$UserName,$Password,$HostURL,$DBName,$LangName,$IncludeChildren,$BackupMode,$VersionNumber,$LookupMode,$DateTime)
    Get-CoreSyncBackup -args $paracs
}
```

Now I want to call this function from remote, I tried using Powershell RemoteAutomation.asmx & PowerShellWebService.asmx but not useful and there is very less documentation about same.
For example i tried to write windows PS file which i can schedule in Job server or any other scheduler as most of them support powershell scripts follows:

```
    $page=New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://audit.brand.com/console/services/RemoteAutomation.asmx"
$BackupFunction=@"
Execute-Script "master:/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/CoreSync/SyncorBackupFunc/";
Execute-Auto-Site-Backup "{7589EBFF-FB47-41A0-8712-E34623F5518E}" "" "sitecore\admin" "b" "http://audit.brand.com/" "master" "en" "true" "true" "" "" ""
"@
$returnVar=""
$page.ExecuteScriptBlock("sitecore\admin","b",$BackupFunction,$returnVar)
$returnvar
```

I also tried following which doesn't worked

```
    $page=New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://audit.brand.com/console/services/RemoteAutomation.asmx"
$BackupFunction=@"
master:/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/CoreSync/SyncorBackupFunc/
"@
$returnVar=""
$page.ExecuteScript("sitecore\admin","b",$BackupFunction,$returnVar)
$returnvar
```

Please guide me where I am wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried applying the solution from [this post on my blog?](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/10/sitecore-powershell-extensions-remoting/)

It should allow you to execute an arbitrary script block on the server.

Comment: Hi @Adam Najmanowicz, 

Your post indicate to use master:/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/Functions/Remoting
which itself mean that you are asking basically to execute the remote script from another Sitecore instance.
Here my scenario need it to execute a remote script which is in Sitecore instance from a local windows PowerShell window. If this becomes possible then I can execute my remote sitecore script in some kind of automation job.

Comment: You can copy the content of that script into a script on your drive and execute that.

Comment: As suggested by the Adam, magic is in following line 
$x = Invoke-SitecoreScript { Execute-Script "master:/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/hello" }
You can do:
$x = Invoke-SitecoreScript { Get-Item "master:/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/hello" | Execute-Script }

Answer (score 0):

Since then we have released an SPE Remoting module that you can use on your local machine to interact with the remote instance of Sitecore.

Read more about it here:
https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/remoting.html